# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception on Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle, exit, reinstall

Hi Im getting this error on my project when trying to build the dlutter app

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                        

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 994

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
   > Could not create task ':app:copyFlutterAssetsRelease'.
      > Could not create task ':app:mergeReleaseAssets'.
         > Cannot use @TaskAction annotation on method IncrementalTask.taskAction$gradle_core() because interface org.gradle.api.tasks.incremental.IncrementalTaskInputs is not a valid parameter to an action method.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 16s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           17.0s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have tried reinstalling flutter and android studio and also tried

```
Pub upgrade
```

And

```
Flutter clean
```

Comment: How about your sdkVersion?

Comment: @AshikulIslamSawan For now im using flutter 3.10.2 stable

Comment: try compileSdkVersion 33 and targetSdkVersion as well

Comment: Still getting the same error